# How to append all elements of an array to a label through a for loop in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, label

I have an array `weekOneExerciseArray` that has 4 strings inside of it. I have a label that I want to assign each of these strings to, each on a new line. At the moment I've just written the individual array elements before attempting to write a more optimised version. However I get

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type

on the `exerciseString = "\(exerciseString)\n (weekOneExerciseArray[exerciseCount])"; }` line.

I've tried so many variants to get this working but to no luck. I would be very thankful for any help!

```
let weekOneExerciseArray = ["Reverse Crunch", "Crunch", "Oblique Crunch", "Rope Crunch"];

//Week 1: 4 exercises
exerciseTextLabel.text = "\(weekOneExerciseArray[0])\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[1])\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[2])\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[3])";


var exerciseString = "";

for exerciseCount in weekOneExerciseArray
{
    exerciseString = "\(exerciseString)\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[exerciseCount])";
}

exerciseTextLabel.text = exerciseString;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The reason for getting the error is** in the `for-in` you are trying to access an element of an array by using a string as an index:

```
for exerciseCount in weekOneExerciseArray
{
    exerciseString = "\(exerciseString)\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[exerciseCount])";
}
```

At this point, `exerciseCount` is a string but *not* an integer, so what you should do instead is:

```
for i in 0..<weekOneExerciseArray.count {
    exerciseString = "\(exerciseString)\n\(weekOneExerciseArray[i])"
}
```

and you would be good to go.

---

### A Better Solution

**However**, I would highly recommend to follow the following approach instead:

You could group up `weekOneExerciseArray` by *joining* its elements using [`joined`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined) method for generating the desired concatenation:

```
let weekOneExerciseArray = ["Reverse Crunch", "Crunch", "Oblique Crunch", "Rope Crunch"]

let concatenatedString = weekOneExerciseArray.joined(separator: "\n")
print(concatenatedString)
/*
 Reverse Crunch
 Crunch
 Oblique Crunch
 Rope Crunch
 */

exerciseTextLabel.text = concatenatedString
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem perfectly and reduced the number of lines I had by quite a lot. I didn't know this existed, thank you!

Comment: Glad to help @MaxGoddard. I edited my answer to tell you what's the reason of your issue :)

Comment: I had no clue I was using the string for the index, probably should've spotted that. Thanks for all your help, this answer was extremely helpful!